# How to make a wrapper function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback, jquery-callback

I have a lot of click handler like below:

```
$(document).on('click','.xxxBtn', function(e){
    ....
})
```

I want to action a cookies saving in some of them.
I can write like below:

```
function defaultHandler (e, callback) {
    callback(e);
    doSomeJobs();
}

$(document).on('click','.xxxBtn', defaultHandler(e,function(e){
    `diferent code in each Btn`
    ....
})
```

But I think it would be nice to use a handle like(**just look more nice and clear**) :

```
$(document).on('click','.xxxBtn', defaultHandler(e){
    `diferent code in each Btn`
    ....
})
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

**update**
em, maybe my example is a little ambiguous. 
I mean that if I can make a `defaultHandler` as what the `function statement` do in javascript? Just `function(e){...}` to  `defaultHandler(e){...}`

Comment: How would `defaultHandler` know what function to call if you don't tell it?

Comment: what wrong with your second use?

Comment: Have you looked up `$.cookie` ..? [link here](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answser**:
No, there is no way to tell it `defaultHandler(e){...}`

**Longer answer**:

It is possible to achieve something very similar to it. What you need are higher order functions, which are functions that return functions. Yes, such a thing is possible in JS, and even necessary to write clean, concise code.

First, let's start with a simple example. You want to have exactly the same handler shared for everything

```
var logArgs = function (e) {
    console.log(arguments);
}

$(document).on('click', '.btn', logArgs);
```

You can use that function as often as you want as an event handler. It'll always work.
But let's assume you need some more specific logic. Maybe you'd like to identify the output by always prepending a certain string.

```
var namedLogger = function (name) {
    return function (e) {
        console.log(name, arguments);
    }
};

$(document).on('click', '.btn', namedLogger('firstButton'));
$(document).on('click', '.btn2', namedLogger('secondButton'));
```

As you can see, we call the function `namedLogger` with a name, which it remembers. Then it returns a new function, which is then used as the event handler. When invoked later, your logger callback will have access to the `name` through the closure scope and log it before the arguments.

You can go crazy with that kind of pattern, and it is actually encouraged.
It's the best way to write reusable event handler code in JS.

To make this more relevant for your use case:

```
var cookieSetter = function (eventHandler) {
    var setCookie = function (key, value) {
        document.cookie = key + '=' + value + ';';
    };

    return function (e) {
        setCookie('whatever', e.something);
        eventHandler(e);
    };
};

$(document).on('click', '.btn', cookieSetter(function (e) {
    console.log('Event triggered', e);
});
```

Comment: em, maybe my example is a little ambiguous. <br>
I mean that if I can make a defaultHandler as what the `function statement` do in javascript? Just `function(e){...}` to  `defaultHandler(e){...}`

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense. Are you sure the example I just added isn't relevant to your problem? It's basically a default handler  that always sets a cookie and then executes the handler passed to it.

Comment: The example you just added is a decorator.It's not so much different to write like `defaultHandler(e,function(e){...} ` in my example.I really think it would be more cozy to write code like `defaultHandler(e){...}`, and that is what I am asking.

Comment: `defaultHandler(e, function (e) {...})` doesn't make a lot of sense, since when you call it there is no `e` yet. But to answer your question, no, there is no way to tell it `defaultHandler(e){...}`. All you can do is using decorators/wrappers for the event handler.

Comment: Yeah, `defaultHandler(e, function (e) {...})` is not make sense, you are right.I just mean that, you know :).Please update you answer, I would choose you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your issue, but maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
function defaultHandler(callback) {
    return function(e) {
        callback(e);
        doSomeJobs();
    }
}
```

Then use it like

```
$(document).on('click', '.xxxBtn', defaultHandler(function(e) {});
```

Answer (score 0):

`defaultHandle(e){...}` is incorrect syntax, you can't.

Use something like followed:

```
function getHandler(flag, next) {
 if (flag) 'store cookies';
 return next;
}

$(document).on('click','.xxxBtn', getHandler(true, function(e){

}));
```

Comment: @MrCode ofcourse! it should be called when clicked.

Comment: nope! you were right previously... as you have parameter(e)

Comment: @C-link, I add explanation, why I wasn't right previously

Comment: every Btn click event function is different, I just want write that more beautiful.

Comment: you changed to function with return but just customHandler without (e) parameter how would work??